# IntelliJ IDEA (Android Studio) Java code formatter enum

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, autoformatting

I have the following code (the first snippet is with IntelliJ autoformat)

```
public enum SampleEnum
{
    YO
        {
            @Override
            public void yo()
            {
                System.out.println("YO");
            }
        }
}
```

and I want it to look like that:

```
public enum SampleEnum
{
    YO
    {
        @Override
        public void yo()
        {
            System.out.println("YO");
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is, how do I do that? The only thing related to enums in the code formatter page is if I want to wrap enum constants, which is no what I want to do.

Comment: @duffymo that gives me the first snippet, just with the println call wrapped. Whats wrong with the second version? Why is it ugly?

Comment: Brace placement doesn't follow Java coding standards.  Open braces belong at the end of the line.

Comment: @duffymo It's my choice whether or not I put braces on a new line. Thats what the formatter is for. I want to have braces on a new line because I can see better which code belongs to which block. Saying it's "ugly" seems a bit intolerant to me.

Comment: Yes, intolerant indeed.  Purely opinion.  But it's a fact that it doesn't follow the Java coding standards.  No argument there.

Comment: @duffymo Exactly. But off-topic. Java coding standards have nothing to do with what I asked.

Comment: Yes they do.  Don't tell me how to comment.

Comment: @duffymo My question was how I can tell the IntelliJ code formatter to format enums like I want them to be formatted, and not if that's conform with java coding standards.